# Website for checking in which programing language code was written?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, web, functional-programming

Do you know any site which can check this?

I think, that i saw sometime ago, some kind of pastebin service which had option "autodetect", but I can't find it anymore. Do you know something which could help me?

---

PS. I am still learning English, however sometimes I am making stupid mistakes. I am doing my best, writing questions and answers in English, however I would be very glad if you will edit my post in case of any mistakes. I promise, your effort will not be wasted.

Answer (score 3):

How about these approaches

Bayesian classifier trained on Alioth shootout code:

http://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2009/01/04/identify-programming-languages-with-source-classifier.html

http://github.com/chrislo/sourceclassifier/tree/master

http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/12/07/word-frequencies/